# How do I display the content of a JavaScript object in a string format using document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, console.log

Want to display my output on screen rather than one console.

```
var str = lowerString.split(" ");
var count = {};
str.forEach(function(s){
    count[s] ? count[s]++ : count[s] = 1;
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count)

Comment: Thanks, it really helped but i have one more query. This code is displaying the following: {"my":1,"name":1,"is":1,"gauri":2,"and":2,"narayan":1,"srijan":1}. How can I delete the curly brackets from printing and display each word in a new line like: "my":1,"name":1,"is":1,"gauri":2,"and":2,"narayan":1,"srijan":1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var lowerString="twst";
var str = lowerString.split(" ");
var count = {};
str.forEach(function(s){
    count[s] ? count[s]++ : count[s] = 1;
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var j = { "my": 1, "name": 1, "is": 1, "gauri": 2, "and": 2, "narayan": 1, "srijan": 1 };
    var s = "";
    for (var k in j) {
      s += k + ":" + j[k] + ',';
    }
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = s;
```

you can replace the last ',' by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const lowerString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lacus purus, volutpat ac arcu sit amet, cursus dapibus odio".split(' ');

const wordCounter = word => lowerString.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? acc[curr] + 1 : 1
  return acc
}, {})[word]

const wordToCount = 'sit';
const wordOccurrences = wordCounter(wordToCount);

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `${wordOccurrences} occurrences found for the word "${wordToCount}"`
```

```html
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

You can use a reducer to create a dict with all occurrences in the string, then you can print on the screen with innerHTML

Comment: I have already tried this with querySelector as well as getElementById both of these have returned [object Object]. But i want to display number of times a word occurs